# React destructuring

Tags: javascript, mern

I am learning mern stack and I am stucked in the following code line-

```
export const register = ({name,email,password})= async dispatch=>{
    const config={
        headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        }
```

It gave the following error in my cmd-

> Parsing error: Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern

```
[1] > 10 | export const register = ({name,email,password})= async dispatch=>{
[1]      |                          ^
[1]   11 |      const config={
[1]   12 |              headers:{
[1]   13 |                      'Content-type':'application/json'
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Your first arrow function is missing a `>`.    Eg.  `({name,email,password})=> async `

Comment: Thank you sir . I did not notice it.

Comment: Thank you sir . I did not notice it.